# Google maps is support select only cities from searchbox?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Now I use

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my api key>&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>
```

But seems it's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found fix of this issue:

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)']
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```